# C++ looping I/O issue

Tags: c++, io

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter command (with arguments) to profile: ";
        std::string command;
        std::cin >> command;
        std::cout << "Running command: " << command << std::endl;
        Process::create(true, command);
    }
}
```

This shouldn't be a difficult issue, but I am a beginner C++ programmer. I have the following code that should loop endlessly, prompting for and accepting user input. It then runs the input as a command to a function I created elsewhere.

The problem is that after the first command is entered, output is printed by the `Process::create` method and when the loop goes back, it uses the data printed instead of accepting my own input. What am I doing wrong? I thought I might need to flush the `cin` stream or something but I have no idea.

Here is an example output to demonstrate my issue:

```
Enter command (with arguments) to profile: ls
Running command: ls
Enter command (with arguments) to profile: homework8      Homework8.cpp~  Process.cpp~    stats.dat
Homework8      plot_stats.gnu  Process.h       TestProgram.cpp
Homework8.cpp  Process.cpp     ProcessStats.h
```

Comment: It's still waiting for you to enter the next command. You probably want to wait for the process to complete before accepting the next command though, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use std::getline to get a string from stream, instead std::cin >> command;

```
std::string command;
std::getline(std::cin, command);
```

Or need check std::cin before get from stream

```
using std::cin;
using std::getline;

char line[MAX_LINE];    /* Line buffer */

while(true)
{
    /* Get command */
    cout << "viettuan@shell:~$ ";
    if (!cin)
        cin.clear();
    else
        cin.getline(line, MAX_LINE);

    //... Do process here
}
```

Comment: I was doing this before I switched to using std::cin >> and it did not work either.

Comment: Try with :
using std::cin;
using std::getline;

char line[MAX_LINE]; /* Line buffer */

while(true)
{
 /* Get command */
 cout << "viettuan@shell:~$ ";
 if (!cin)
  cin.clear();
 cin.getline(line, MAX_LINE);

 //... Do process here
}

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::getline` to get a whole line. Doing `std::cin >> command;` stops at the first whitespace, so if you enter a command with arguments then you will go through several iterations of the loop for that line.

```
while ( std::getline(std::cin, command ) 
{
    std::cout << "Running command: " << command << std::endl;
    Process::create(true, command);
}

// getting here means they closed stdin
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter command (with arguments) to profile: ";
        std::string command;
        std::cin >> command;
        std::cout << "Running command: " << command << std::endl;
        Process::create(true, command);
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.sync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still seems to be causing me the same issue.